# git reporting checked out subdirectory as untracked

Tags: git, npm

I have checked out a clean branch with a `node_modules` subdirectory. When I do `git status`, I get:

```
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/development'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        node_modules/.bin/_mocha
        node_modules/.bin/mkdirp
        node_modules/.bin/mocha
        etc.
```

for the hundreds of files in that folder. I have tried `git checkout HEAD -- node_modules` but it still reports the folder as untracked.

Comment: What is the content of the `.gitignore` file on this branch? And what is the content of the `.gitignore` file in the previous branch?

Answer (score 0):

Untracked files are files/directories that are not part of the repository.
This means git does not know about these files or where they came from.

Doing a `git checkout` or a `git reset` will not affect them, since they're not *tracked* by git.

You can safely ignore them if it worries you. If you want git to not show them when you do `git status`, you need to add the directory/files in a file called the [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) at the base/root of your repo.

Comment: They are part of the repo because I checked them out of the repo. This was a fresh checkout from the server.

Comment: @MusicalShore are you sure these files weren't created when you ran something inside the repo? Can you check the ctime on those files to see if those files were created before or after the clone? What's your .gitignore look like? You might also want to try `git reset --hard origin/master` if you're not worried about losing any work.

Comment: The .gitignore in that branch makes no reference to that path or files. I did not do a clone, I deleted the local branch and then checked out the remote branch using SourceTree. At the time I did that, I was in another branch that did not have the node_modules folder. As I understand it, the HEAD pointer should have been moved to the branch node that had that folder in it. When I checkout a remote branch, doesn't it just pull the HEAD downstream, so the files should be in local HEAD? And if I do commit them, what happens when I push upstream where the files already exist?